# Accessing WooCommerce 2.0 Subscriptions directly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been accessing WooCommerce Subscriptions from my Wordpress installation directly this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta`
    WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%woocommerce_subscriptions'
    AND   `user_id`=0000
```

But with WooCommerce 2.x, the Subscriptions Schema has been changed. From the documentation:

> #### Subscription Storage & Access
>
> It is strongly recommended you access subscriptions and their associated meta data through API functions, like [`WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_subscription()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/management-functions/#section-1). The storage schema is scheduled to be changed with Subscriptions version 2.0. API functions will maintain backwards compatibility, but if accessing data directly, you should expect your code to break with version 2.0.

Does anyone have figured out how to access the subscription data directly from the database with WooCommerce 2.x?

Comment: What is wrong with using `WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_subscriptions()` ?

Comment: It loads the whole WP Plugin @helgatheviking, which is a worst nightmare for performance. `:(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `meta_value` like this:

```
SELECT Count({$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value) > 0 AS mVal
FROM   {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta
       LEFT JOIN {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_items
              ON {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id =
                 {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
       LEFT JOIN {$wp_prefix}postmeta
              ON {$wp_prefix}postmeta.post_id = {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_items.order_id
       LEFT JOIN {$wp_prefix}posts
              ON {$wp_prefix}postmeta.post_id = {$wp_prefix}posts.id
WHERE  ( {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key IN (
                  '_subscription_status-Yikes', '_subscription_end_date',
                  '_subscription_start_date-Yikes',
                  '_subscription_period- Yikes' ) )
       AND post_status != 'wc-pending'
       AND {$wp_prefix}postmeta.meta_value = (SELECT id
                                        FROM   {$wp_prefix}users
                                        WHERE  user_url = 'http://{$subDomain}')
       AND {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value = 0;
```

Where the `{$wp_prefix}` should be your prefix. The final code would be:

```
$subscription = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT({$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value) > 0 AS mVal FROM {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta LEFT JOIN {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_items ON {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id LEFT JOIN {$wp_prefix}postmeta ON {$wp_prefix}postmeta.post_id = {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_items.order_id LEFT JOIN {$wp_prefix}posts ON {$wp_prefix}postmeta.post_id = {$wp_prefix}posts.ID WHERE ({$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key IN ('_subscription_status-Yikes', '_subscription_end_date', '_subscription_start_date-Yikes', '_subscription_period- Yikes') ) AND post_status != 'wc-pending' AND {$wp_prefix}postmeta.meta_value = (SELECT ID FROM {$wp_prefix}users WHERE user_url = 'http://{$subDomain}') AND {$wp_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value = 0"));
$subscription = $subscription[0];
```

Test for the `$subscription` to be `1` to be subscriber.